# Dynamic where clause in LINQ to Objects

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects, dynamic-linq

I know there are a lot of examples of this on the web, but I can't seem to get this to work.

Let me try to set this up, I have a list of custom objects that I need to have limited on a range of values.

I have a sort variable that changes based on some action on the UI, and I need to process the object differently based on that.

Here is my object:

```
MyObject.ID - Just an identifier
MyObject.Cost - The cost of the object.
MyObject.Name - The name of the object.
```

Now I need to filter this based on a range in the cost, so I will have something similar to this, considering that I could be limiting by Either of my bottom two properties.

```
var product = from mo in myobject 
              where mo.Cost <= 10000
```

or

```
var product = from mo in myobject
              where mo.Name equals strName
```

Now I have the dynamic linq in my project, but I'm not figuring out how to get it to actually work, as when I do some of the examples I am only getting:

```
Func<Tsourse>bool> predicate
```

as an option.

**Update:**
I am trying to find a solution that helps me Objectify my code, as right now it is a lot of copy and paste for my linq queries.

**Update 2:**
Is there an obvious performance difference between:

```
var product = from mo in myobject 
... a few joins ...
where mo.Cost <= 10000
```

and

```
var product = (from mo in myobject 
... a few joins ...)
.AsQueryable()
.Where("Cost > 1000")
```

Comment: doesn't where mo.Cost <= 10000 || mo.Name equals strName work?

Comment: Did you add `System.Linq.Dynamic` to the `using`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe not directly answering your question, but DynamicQuery is unnecessary here.  You can write this query as:

```
public IEnumerable<MyObject> GetMyObjects(int? maxCost, string name)
{
    var query = context.MyObjects;
    if (maxCost != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(mo => mo.Cost <= (int)maxCost);
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
    {
        query = query.Where(mo => mo.Name == name);
    }
    return query;
}
```

If the conditions are mutually exclusive then just change the second `if` into an `else if`.

I use this pattern all the time.  What "Dynamic Query" really means is combining pure SQL with Linq; it doesn't really help you that much with generating conditions on the fly.

Comment: I think was just using those `where` as mere examples, i think he means that he may have many different filters.

Comment: @Stan: It doesn't matter how many different filters there are, you can keep building up the expression this way indefinitely.  Under the hood, this is exactly what writing a regular `from x in y` query expression does, but without the conditionals.  DynamicQuery is only for use when you need to write your queries as strings; if you're using lambda expressions, you don't need it.

Comment: @Aaronaught, you can't keep writing many different filters as there maybe an enormous amount of variations. Say you have 5 fields that's more than 200 possible filter combination's.

Comment: @Stan: If you have 5 fields, that's 5 `if` statements.  The number of possible combinations does not matter - and even if it did, how would DynamicQuery help?  Don't get me wrong, DynamicQuery is a great add-on, it's just not needed here.

Comment: This is somewhat what I was looking for, and I am going to give this a shot.  I do have a limited number of possibilities, so this would be very maintainable.

Comment: @Aaronaught, i do agree with you...this is why I changed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Read this great post on DLINQ by  ScottGu

[Dynamic LINQ (Part 1: Using the LINQ Dynamic Query Library)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

You would need something like

```
var product = myobject.Where("Cost <= 10000");
var product = myobject.Where("Name = @0", strName);
```

If you downloaded the samples you need to find the `Dynamic.cs` file in the sample. You need to copy this file into your project and then add
`using System.Linq.Dynamic;` to the class you are trying to use Dynamic Linq in.

EDIT: To answer your edit. Yes, there is of course a performance difference. If you know the variations of filters beforehand then I would suggest writing them out without using DLINQ.

You can create your own Extension Method like so.

```
 public static class FilterExtensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T> AddFilter<T,T1>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Func<T,T1, bool> filter,  T1 argument )
        {
            return list.Where(foo => filter(foo, argument) );
        }
    }
```

Then create your filter methods.

```
        public bool FilterById(Foo obj, int id)
        {
            return obj.id == id;
        }

        public bool FilterByName(Foo obj, string name)
        {
            return obj.name == name;
        }
```

Now you can use this on an `IEnumerable<Foo>` very easily.

```
    List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>();
    foos.Add(new Foo() { id = 1, name = "test" });
    foos.Add(new Foo() { id = 1, name = "test1" });
    foos.Add(new Foo() { id = 2, name = "test2" });

    //Example 1
    //get all Foos's by Id == 1
    var list1 = foos.AddFilter(FilterById, 1);

    //Example 2
    //get all Foo's by name ==  "test1"
    var list2 = foos.AddFilter(FilterByName, "test1");

    //Example 3
   //get all Foo's by Id and Name
   var list1 = foos.AddFilter(FilterById, 1).AddFilter(FilterByName, "test1");
```

Comment: Read my question, I said I have that in my project but can't get it to actually work.

Comment: That's because you need to actually use the DLINQ extension methods.

Comment: What does that mean?  If I understood what I was doing wrong, I wouldn't be asking here.

Comment: If it, is using the .  As I said, every time I type that... I get the Func<... in my intellisense and not the dynamic options.

Comment: You downloaded DLINQ, but have you added it as a reference to your project and use the correct namespace?

Comment: I added the dynamic.cs to my business layer DLL, and added the namespace.  

I can get it to show if I put .asqueryable() on my objects, but in the overall solution I have that isn't realistic where I need to use it.

Comment: @Clarence, thats because if you look at the source code you will see that the extension methods all extend `IQueryable` rather than `IEnumerable` this is why you don't see the methods unless you use `AsQueryable()` method.

Comment: I am going to edit my question a bit, to see if you could help answer a follow up to this that isn't appropriate for a comment.

Comment: @Clarence, I updated my answer, hope you find the code sample useful

Comment: @Stan, thank you for your help.  Gave you a +1, but the solution offered by @Aaron was a bit more fitting for my situation.  Though your solution was totally acceptable as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Linq;

var products = mo.Where(x => x.Name == "xyz");

var products = mo.Where(x => x.Cost <= 1000);

var products = mo.Where(x => x.Name == "xyz" || x.Cost <= 1000);
```